# Skype segmentation fault ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 64-bit, skype, 13.04, segmentation-fault

Skype (from depots and website) Crashes with :

> Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
>   Tried to reinstall, no .skype in my /home

Maybe a clue : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154571
I'll make some more tests When I have some time.

Thx

Comment: 13.04 is unsupported here until it's final release.  I suggest filing a bug against skype.  [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).